# How to resolve runtime error "SIGSEGV" in codechef?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am facing the runtime error and WA while submitting, my code is pretty basic so you can look into it

Problem: https://www.codechef.com/problems/PLAYFIT

Solution(getting "SIGSEGV"):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  //taking test cases
    int T=0;
    scanf("%d", T);
    
    while(T--){
      
      int N=0, diff=0, maxDif=-1, gi=0, gj=0;
      //taking N
      scanf("%d", N);
      //taking match 1 goals
      scanf("%d", gi);
      
      for(int i=1;i<N;i++){
        //taking consecutuve goals in match
        scanf("%d", gj);
        //calc diff
        diff = gj - gi;
        
        if (diff > maxDif){
          maxDif = diff;
        }
        gi = gj;
      }
      
      //output
      if(maxDif >0){
        //cout<<maxDif<<endl;
        printf("%d \n", maxDif);
      }else{
        //cout<<"UNFIT"<<endl;
        printf("UNFIT \n");
      }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

What I expect is

1. Solution and explanation why I am getting runtime error/
2. Better approach towards solving this particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the `scanf` [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html). This: `scanf("%d", T);` should be `scanf("%d", &T);` instead.

Other calls to `scanf()` have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks btw I tried cin as well but that does not work